# C# Arrays in List printing to console in formatted way

Tags: c#, arrays, list, console

Basically I want to print the contents of a list in the console in a formatted manner like so:

[image: expected output]

However what i currently have:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nHistory |  B W");
Console.WriteLine("================");

List.AddRange(array1);
List.Add(array2);
List.Add(array3);

foreach (int i in List)
 {
   Console.Write(i);
 }
```

Prints it like this:

[image: actual output]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `List`? What is `array1`? What is `array2`? What is `array3`? What data you have there?

Comment: List is a List<> containing the information in array1 , array2, array3. Array1 is history, array2 is B and array3 is W. And the data is just random integers i am using for demonstration. Thank you

Comment: Your list should be a list of some type of complex object that has 3 fields.  As it is you have no way of knowing when your list has reached the "end of the line", or even where the line between the end of the first field and the start of the second field is.  Until you fix your data model you cannot display it correctly.

Comment: @user3352356 all arrays have same number of items?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes they are all the same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution if all arrays have same length:

```
string rowFormat = "{0,15}|{1,3} {2,3}";
Console.WriteLine(rowFormat, "History", "B", "W");
Console.WriteLine(new String('=', 25));

for(int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)    
    Console.WriteLine(rowFormat, array1[i], array2[i], array3[i]);
```

But I would suggest to use custom type for your data instead of keeping data in three arrays. E.g. (names according to your comments)

```
public class UserGuess
{
    public int AttemptNumber { get; set; }
    public int BlacksCount { get; set; }
    public int WhitesCount { get; set; }
}
```

But formatting will stay same:

```
foreach(var g in guesses)
    Console.WriteLine(rowFormat, 
       g.AttemptNumber, g.BlacksCount, f.WhitesCount);
```

NOTE: As [The format item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) section on String.Format documentation states, format item has following syntax `{ index[,alignment][ :formatString] }`. So, code above just uses `alignment` parameter to set fixed total length of field.

Comment: Yes i would tend to agree except i cannot use .Length and the array size is user defined so unknown until application runs.

Comment: @user3352356 so arrays are not arrays? What data type you have?

Comment: All are using integers, however the user is asked how big the array needs to be, then the array is declared as size A (A being user input int). So int[] array = new int[A]

Comment: @user3352356 so data type is array. Can you explain why `Length` is not available to you?

Comment: The "challenge" is to not use anything other than for loops, and basic code. Which apparently .Length does not fall into....

Comment: @user3352356 why Length does not fall into? Sorry, I can't understand it

Comment: I know its the teacher i have being difficult!!!! However using a list means i can dynamically add to it as required. Thus the running history

Comment: @user3352356 your problem is not clear. If you are using arrays, then you are using their `Length` property. If you need to iterate over array, you use a loop. That is how C# works

Comment: haha sorry Sergey i will try to clear it up. So i am trying to create a Mastermind console based game that uses numbers instead of colours. The piece of code above is the running history of the guesses the user has made. This is why you have 'History' as four integers (the user guesses), then B (black) which is correct number in correct position, and W (white) which is correct number in wrong position. So it needs to print as show so that the user can see their running history of guesses, correct and incorrect attempts. Hopefully that makes more sense :)

Comment: So basically the two images above are the exact same pieces of information and each line under 'History' represents a turn the user has taken so to speak. Is just as you can see in my current situation the formatting is completely wrong, it is just adding the history to one line.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the documentation?

- [System.Console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In particular, look at the various `Write()` and `WriteLine()` overloads. **Hint:** `WriteLine()` appends a line break at the end of what it writes; `Write()` does not.
- [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I'm sure you'll figure it out.